# Быстрое получение значений атрибутов HTML -страницы

Tags: java, парсер

Добрый день. Использовал Jsoup, чтобы получить значения всех атрибутов по имении из HTML-страницы. Но как по мне, не очень быстро. Возможно есть что-то менее функциональное, но более быстрое? Главное, чтобы можно было получить значения атрибутов по имени.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что не очень быстро. Есть бенчмарки?
Быстрее будет только самописный велосипед под конкретную задачу.

Comment: @MoS1993 просто взял 2 System.out.println("Начало/конец") :D